# why this code to print nth number giving runtime error?

Tags: c

We have to print the nth term of a series whose first three terms are given as `a, b, c` and nth term is sum of previous three terms.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Complete the following function.

int find_nth_term(int n, int a, int b, int c) {
    //Write your code here.
    int i, arr[n];
    arr[0] = a;
    arr[1] = b;
    arr[2] = c;
    if (n >= 3 && i <= n) {
       arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2] + arr[i - 3];
       //using recursion to find nth term 
       return find_nth_term(n, a, b, c);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, a, b, c;

    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &n, &a, &b, &c);
    int ans = find_nth_term(n, a, b, c);

    printf("%d", ans); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The return type of `find_nth_term()` function is `int`, yet you don't seem to return an actual value. Your `return` statement is empty in the `else` statement.

Comment: Also, your `i` is never initialized.

Comment: @Inrin However, that isn't throwing any error when I run the code.

Comment: Compile your code with `-Wall` and your compiler will complain.
It's pure (bad) luck you didn't get an segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not `return`ing anything if the `if` statement in your function evaluates to `False`. You've set the `return` type of your function as `int` but you're not actually `return`ing anything.

Change that line to:

```
return (a + b + c);
```

Also, as @Inrin notes in the comments, you never initialise `i`.

Answer (score 0):

So two things:

Thing 1: You are declaring an array of length N and then accessing from 0 to N (i.e. N+1 variables) which will cause a memory leak.

Thing 2: Why are you doing this recursively when a for loop is so much easier:

```
for(i = 3; i<n; i++)
{
   arr[i]=arr[i-1]+arr[i-2]+arr[i-3];
}
return (arr[n-1]);
```

Comment: it was just a task to do it recursively

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect for multiple reasons:

- you do not return anything when not recursing.
- you do not compute the correct value in the recursion expression
- the array `arr` should just have 3 elements, not `n`
- you do not handle values of `n` below `3`
- there is no need for recursion, a simple iterative approach is enough.

Here is a corrected recursive version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_nth_term(int n, int a, int b, int c) {
    int arr[3];
    if (n < 3) {
       if (n < 0) {
           return 0;
       } else {
           arr[0] = a;
           arr[1] = b;
           arr[2] = c;
           return arr[n];
    } else {
       return find_nth_term(n - 1, b, c, a + b + c);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n, a, b, c, ans;

    if (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &n, &a, &b, &c) == 4) {
        ans = find_nth_term(n, a, b, c);
        printf("%d\n", ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an alternative approach without recursion:

```
int find_nth_term(int n, int a, int b, int c) {
    int arr[3];

    if (n < 0)
       return 0;

    arr[0] = a;
    arr[1] = b;
    arr[2] = c;
    while (n >= 3) {
        int v = arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2];
        arr[0] = arr[1];
        arr[1] = arr[2];
        arr[2] = v;
    }
    return arr[n];
}
```

Note that the *n-th* term in the above code is 0 based, meaning `find_nth_term(1, a, b, c)` returns `b`. If you want it to return `a` instead, some minor adjustments are needed.